# Why did One Piece chapter 750 come out late?

Tags: one-piece

I have been waiting and waiting and have been checking every website about *One Piece*, and I couldn't find anything.

Are there any reasons why chapter 750 came out late?

Answer (score 11):

*One Piece* has been on hiatus for 2 weeks (*Weekly Shonen Jump* issue 28 & 29) since Oda was getting some sort of surgery done. It should be back in the next issue (issue 30).

> [image: last page of One Piece c749]